# Regular expression for rails have 3 digit length and starting with only 4 and 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to make regular expression that start with only 4 and 5 and have three length string

including first digit 4 and 5.

```
   like "455"
   like "555"
```

Thanks.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
/^[45]\d{2}$/
```

[example](http://rubular.com/r/T7Ggwuleuo)